# Why doesn't my trackpad \ touchpad work on my USB boot of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, usb, mouse, touchpad

I created a bootable flash drive to run Ubuntu on as I have a pretty old laptop with an extremely small hard drive. I had now problems getting it to boot up, but my trackpad (mouse) isn't operational. An ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.
I am going to buy a wireless mouse and see if that makes a difference. I can only assume it is the drivers, but I can't navigate too much on Ubuntu with only the tab button.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Does it meet the hardware requirements of the version of Ubuntu you are trying to install? Not really a point to this question till you have a working mouse.

Comment: Does it work with an external wired mouse?

Comment: I don't have one to try, but that was my thought so I will probably have to go pick one up and see. As to the version, I am not sure. I am new to Ubuntu and I just downloaded a trial version.

Comment: There are no trial versions. Downloads are here https://ubuntu.com/#download which one did you pick?

Comment: Ubunto 20.04 LTS